# Moving from one nest fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-nested-fragment

I'm new to Android and I'm playing with `Fragment`s, I know that there exist many examples to learn how `Fragment`s work, unfortunately there is not many examples using `Nested-Fragment`s (which are in the same `Activity`).
This is my code below, ive encountered 2 problems:

1. The `Root` `Fragment` is visible after I add the secondary `Fragment`.
2. both `Fragment` use same design, but when I add the `Fragment`Ii can see the dimensions of the widgets and the position on the screen are not the same.
3. I Need some feedback how to do it right.

Thank you!

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,
                    container, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signUpText1);
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.loginViewPlaceholder, new SignupFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

        public SignupFragment() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View signupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup,
                    container, false);
            return signupView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say that the `Fragment`s use the same "Design" do you mean that their `xml` layouts are the same?

Comment: You will probably have to show the XML layouts for your fragments (fragment_login.xml, fragment_signup.xml) for anyone to be able to diagnose why they appear visually different on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` method will remove a fragment from the specified container and add the new one its place. In your example, it looks like you are adding the `PlaceholderFragment` to the container `android.R.content` and the `SignupFragment` to the container `R.id.loginViewPlaceholder`. If you want the `SignupFragment` to replace the `PlaceholderFragment` you will have to either use the same container for both, or you will have to do separate `remove()` and `add()` calls for your transaction.